# Symfony match a route to host is not working

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8, symfony-routing

I need to set a route in my Symfony (2.8) project to be loaded when one of the sub domains are accessed. Let's say my site is hosted under "example.com" and its admin needs to be loaded for "admin.example.com". 
I know in Symfony we can use `host: admin.example.com` in the routing file (as instructed in http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/routing/hostname_pattern.html). 
But when I add it in any of the routing.yml files (app/config/routing.yml and AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml) it does not work.

I get the error

> No route found for "GET /admin/"

How can I load a different bundle when a sub domain is called? What am I doing wrong here?

app/config/routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
    prefix:   /

admin:
    resource: "@AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin/
```

AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
admin_homepage:
    path:     /
    host:     admin.example.com
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Index:home }
```

Comment: can you share please your routing file : AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

Answer (score 2):

I think you should swap host and prefix positions like this:

```
    app:
        resource: '@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
        prefix:   /

    admin:
        resource: "@AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        host:     admin.example.com
```

```
    admin_homepage:
        path:     /admin
        defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Index:home }
```

Comment: Is there any way to test this out in localhost?